# Chrome Devtools / Inspector: Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between css properties in the Styles tab?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I generally use Firefox and Firebug to test and tweak CSS, but am attempting to make the switch to Chrome. One thing that is driving me absolutely crazy is that to change a CSS property in Chrome, it looks like I have to click it, erase the current value, and type in the correct value manually.

In Firebug, you simply click a property and push up/down to switch between that rule's valid properties, so for instance if you're playing around with `justify-content:` pushing `up/down` would switch between center/start/end/right/etc. In Chrome, I'm finding I have to look up syntax all the time and it's wasting my time. This functionality is present on newly-typed rules, but not on existing rules, I think.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between valid properties on an existing css rule in the Styles tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl-Space` is the keyboard shortcut. Still significantly slower than the new rule / Firebug `up/down` method, but at least it works.